# MariaDB JSON functions

Tags: mariadb, json

I am using MariaDB 10.5, I have a JSON field in a table which typical contains something like:

```
[{"Filename":"C:/Users/simon/Documents/file.ext"},{"Soil":"Sand"},{"Present":"None"},{"Value":"5000"}]
```

I want to construct queries that can look for matches in the database, so I might have a **QStringList** containing:

```
Soil:Sand
Value:5000
```

Where the value left of the colon is the JSON member name and the value on the right is the value to compare.

How can I use these to construct a query where the table name is for example: datasets and the field is jsonParams ?

Answer (score 1):

Use JSON_SEARCH().

```sql
...
WHERE JSON_SEARCH(value, 'one', 'Sand', NULL, '$[*].Soil') IS NOT NULL
```

Your method with JSON_VALUE() is applicable if there is only one `"Soil"` attribute per the whole value.

See <kbd>**[DEMO fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=770437245be917a161893749d0e5bae4)**</kbd>

Comment: There is only one of each in each object.

Answer (score 0):

Done...I used the function **JSON_VALUE** like so:

```
SELECT
  biPK
FROM
  datasets
WHERE
  JSON_VALUE(jsonParams, '$[*].Soil')='Sand'
```

The [*] above tells it to look for any index in an array for the term 'Soil' and compare with 'Sand'.